# How to \@gobble the Dotfill Attached to Section Entries in the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, tocloft, remove

When I use the command `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{}`, `\tocloft` seems to automatically insert a dotfill and a page number.

I want neither of these for *section* entries.

I have managed to eliminate the page number by using

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\@gobble}
\makeatother
```

But I have not been able to figure out a way to eliminate the dots that stretch across to the vicinity of the missing page number.

QUESTION: Is there a simple way to do this; something perhaps along the lines of the above macro which nicely "gobbled up" the unwanted page number?  Thank you.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage  % Clears all blank pages
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vspace*{5pt}} % Space after each Chapter in the Table of Contents
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vspace*{7pt}}  % Space after each Section in the Table of Contents

% Removes page number for section entries in TOC.
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\@gobble}
\makeatother

% Centers "Contents"
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}

% Dotfill for Chapters
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\dotfill}
%\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\dotfill}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter*{1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{1. Title for Chapter 1}
\section*{1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Title for Section 1}
\end{document}
```

which produces the *Content* output

[image]

Comment: if tocloft doesn't offfer anything you could simply redefine `\l@section`  which is only one line in `report` class the full definition is `\newcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}`  and you want to define it more like `\l@chapter` which is the line above which doesn't use dottedtocline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always a good idea to read the manual, this one-liner solves both problems, no need for strange gobble effects.

```
\cftpagenumbersoff{section}
```

Comment: Many thanks for this very nice and simple solution---which takes care of both problems simultaneously.